# WooCommerce show on-sale badge only for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, badge

I want to display sale bubble in WooCommerce only for logged in users.
I have a function which hides sale-bubble for unlogged users but if I log in there is showing only value "1" instead of sale-bubble.
I know why, because I am returning a true, but I cant figure out how to return sale-bubble instead of true..

WooCommerce

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'woo_custom_hide_sales_flash');
function woo_custom_hide_sales_flash()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the return value of the filter function is displayed. try returning your woocommerce_sales_flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using this filter hook in the right way. Try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'filter_sales_flash_callback', 100, 3 );
function filter_sales_flash_callback( $output_html, $post, $product )
{
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $output_html = false;
    }
    return $output_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sales_badge() {   
    global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_on_sale() ) return;
   if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100;
   } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = 0;
      foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
         $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );
         $price = $variation->get_regular_price();
         $sale = $variation->get_sale_price();
         if ( $price != 0 && ! empty( $sale ) ) $percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;
         if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {
            $max_percentage = $percentage;
         }
      }
   }
   if ( $max_percentage > 0 ) { ?>
        <span class="prinjal-sale-badge"><?php echo round($max_percentage) . "%"; ?></span>    
       <?php
   }
}

// use shortcode instead of action and then use shortcode anywhere you want to ouptut it
add_shortcode( 'custom_sales_badge', 'sales_badge' );
```

my problem solve using this code you can place any ware you want to display sale badge

Answer (score -1):

```
function sales_markup() {   

    if(!is_admin()) { 

    if(is_user_logged_in())    {  
     // Instead of outputting add the markup that you want to show  
     $output = '<div class="Sales_markup_here">
      </div>';
     return $output;

     }
  }
}

// use shortcode instead of action and then use shortcode anywhere you want to ouptut it
add_shortcode( 'sales_markup', 'sales_markup' );
```

Use the shortcode where you want to output the bubble. You can add the css in the global css file.